# How to do a database transaction with Joomla Jtable

Tags: php, joomla, transactions

I'm inserting data to a table in Joomla

```
foreach($resultarray as $data1)
{
  $table = JTable::getInstance('Upload', 'UsersTable', array());
  $table->bind($data1);
  $table->store();
}
```

I want to do a transaction so that there will be START TRANSACTION, COMMIT

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Joomla Joomla 3.x introduced SQL transactions (where supported) via the JDatabaseDriver's transactionStart, transactionCommit and transactionRollback. This supersedes the queryBatch method which was introduced in Joomla Joomla 2.5.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

try
{
$db->transactionStart();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$values = array($db->quote('TEST_CONSTANT'), $db->quote('Custom'), $db->quote('/path/to/translation.ini'));

$query->insert($db->quoteName('#__overrider'));
$query->columns($db->quoteName(array('constant', 'string', 'file')));
$query->values(implode(',',$values));

$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->execute();

$db->transactionCommit();
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
// catch any database errors.
$db->transactionRollback();
JErrorPage::render($e);
}
```

i have picked this example from [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Using_transactions_in_Joomla)

Comment: Your hint for the Joomla SQL transactions is right. But is this also supported on the table-level like mentioned in the question?

Comment: (When I said "does not seem to work", I mean $db->transactionRollback(); does not do anything; it does not rollback, nor does it throw an exception.)